# What can we infer about an individual from a distribution over the population?

Tags: interpretation, inference, philosophical

This is a somewhat philosophical question, or maybe it has to do with the interpretation of statistics. The question is: if we have a distribution of some property of a large population, but then look at one individual from that population in particular, what can we really say about that property for this individual?

We can say "this individual has an 80% chance of being less than 6'5", but that is kind of "circular", in the sense that it means "if we were to take 100 individuals, roughly 80 would be less than 6'5", which involves the population again, rather than definitely saying something about this individual at hand. So, do the stats actually say anything about this particular individual? In what sense?

(This is most probably a well known question that has already been debated by statisticians - any references or pointers to literature would be welcome.)

Comment: 1. Once you have the individual, their attributes are no longer random (they're fixed); before you select, you can make probability statements, assuming you're selecting at random from that population. 2. If you don't know how the individual will be selected you won't be able to make probability statements like that. For example, you may know that adult males in a particular place have a particular distribution for height, but if your individual was to be (by convenience) the first player to walk off a basketball court at the end of a given game... such probability statements would be wrong.